# wxPython paint event works on Mac OSX but not Windows

Tags: python, wxpython

In my wxPython GUI, I'm trying to direct the user to a particular widget.

In my simplified code, the desired behavior is this: click on button two, which causes a red line to be drawn around button one as soon as a paint event is fired.  This behavior works as expected on OSX, but the line doesn't show up on Windows. Here is some simplified code:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, name='Name')
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, name='main_panel')
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, 'button 1')
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, 'button 2')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.do_button, self.btn2)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)                                            
        sizer.Add(self.btn1, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        sizer.Add(self.btn2, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def do_button(self, event):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.highlight_button)

    def highlight_button(self, event):
        """                                                                                          
        Draw a red highlight line around button 1                                           
        """
        wind = self.btn1
        pos = wind.GetPosition()
        size = wind.GetSize()
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 5, wx.SOLID))
        dc.DrawRectangle(pos[0], pos[1], size[0], size[1])
        self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
app.frame = MyFrame()
app.frame.Centre()
app.frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I am successfully catching the paint events on Windows, but the red line never shows up.  I'm using Windows 10, wxPython 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a few problems ... I will only partially address them

first you are drawing on your frame , which is covered by your panel, so you dont see your drawing ... (an easy fix, although probably not quite what you want is as follows)

```
def InitUI(self):
    self.panel = self # wx.Panel(self, name='main_panel')
    ... # rest of this method stays the same
```

more likely you will want to bind the EVT_PAINT to the panel rather than the frame

2nd problem is that even though you bind the EVT_PAINT in the EVT_BUTTON, wx will still not trigger event paint (it only redraws dirty things...) you can trigger an `EVT_PAINT` with `self.Refresh()` or or various other activities that will make the wx.Frame dirty ...    in this instance we can probably just force a refresh

```
def do_button(self, event):
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.highlight_button)
    self.Refresh()
```

there additionally there is really no reason to call `self.Refresh()` inside your EVT_PAINT handler `highlight_button` I dont think you need the `event.Skip()` either ...

```
def highlight_button(self, event):
    """
    Draw a red highlight line around button 1
    """
    wind = self.btn1
    pos = wind.GetPosition()
    size = wind.GetSize()
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 5, wx.SOLID))
    dc.DrawRectangle(pos[0], pos[1], size[0], size[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It looks like, additionally, I need to change this line: `dc = wx.PaintDC(self)` to `dc=wx.PaintDC(self.panel)`.